# Generating SARIMA data and using it to evaluate the accuracy of the `predict` function, but getting some weird plots

Tags: r, arima, prediction, aic

I have written the following code to generate 500 data points from a $SARIMA$ model, use $400$ as training data and then predict the following $100$, while estimating the model with AIC. It appeared to me that I did everything correctly as I could see the AIC correctly choosing the model with certain phi values, etc. etc., however my plot outputs for the estimations is very very dense and incomprehensible and I'm not sure why. I checked the number of data points, the window size, etc. and am not sure what I have done wrong in my implementation.

```
library(CombMSC)
library(forecast)


#####################
#generate data
sdat1<- sarima.Sim(n=500, period=12, model = list(order = c(1,0,0), ar=0.5),list(order= c(1,0,0), ar = 0.5))
#procure training data
x.tr <- window(sdat1, start=1, end=400)

#candidate models
op1 <- arima(x.tr, order=c(0,0,0), list(order= c(0,1,0)))
op2 <- arima(x.tr, order=c(1,0,0), list(order= c(1,0,1)))
op3 <- arima(x.tr, order=c(1,0,0), list(order= c(0,2,0)))
op4 <- arima(x.tr, order=c(0,1,0), list(order= c(0,0,0)))
op5 <- arima(x.tr, order=c(1,0,1), list(order= c(0,0,0)))
op6 <- arima(x.tr, order=c(1,0,0), list(order= c(1,0,0)))

models <- c(op1,op2,op3,op4,op5,op6)
models.AIC <- c(op1$aic,op2$aic,op3$aic,op4$aic,op5$aic,op6$aic)
mod.best = NULL
if (min(models.AIC) == op1$aic){
    mod.best=op1
} else if (min(models.AIC) == op2$aic){
    mod.best=op2
} else if (min(models.AIC) == op3$aic){
    mod.best=op3
} else if (min(models.AIC) == op4$aic){
    mod.best=op4
} else if (min(models.AIC) == op5$aic){
    mod.best=op5 
} else if (min(models.AIC) == op6$aic){
    mod.best=op6
}
models.AIC
mod.best
modpred <- predict(mod.best, n.ahead=100)
vld.data1<-  sdat1[401:500]
plot.ts(sdat1, ylim=c(floor(min(sdat1)),ceiling(max(sdat1))))
plot.ts(sdat1, xlim=c(0,400),ylim=c(floor(min(sdat1)),ceiling(max(sdat1)))) 
lines(modpred$pred, col='blue')
lines(modpred$pred-(1.96*modpred$se), col='red')
lines(modpred$pred+(1.96*modpred$se), col='red')
```

[image]

Comment: Looks OK to me. 500 data points in one plot is dense by construction. You could try plotting subsamples, e.g. 1 through 100, 101 through 200 and so on. Also, your title does not accurately reflect you problem, in my opinion; It is all about the plot, and there may be nothing wrong with the model or predictions.

Comment: @RichardHardy For my plot of the first 400 points and subsequent prediction, I sort of required all 500 points I think. Is there any way I could make the plot look less dense? Maybe only displaying every $n$-th point or something? Or would that compromise the purpose of the plot? And my apologies about the title, I'd welcome any suggestion to change it.

Comment: I don't see how you could make it less dense unless you physically increase the box (make it wider). That can be done by specifying the parameter `width` in function `dev.new`, e.g. `dev.new(width=20,height=4)`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are simulating 500 years * 12 observations by years, not 500 observations. You must do:

```
sarima.Sim(n=500/12, period=12, model=list(order=c(1,0,0),
 ar=0.5), list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=0.5))
```